Is $\iint u(x,y)v(x,y)dxdy$ equal to $\int u(x,y)dv(x,y)$ always? And if it is true, how to prove it?
I am studying about the Wasserstein distance. And I came across the following function for calculating the cost of moving one probability distribution into another.
$$\iint c(x,y)\gamma(x,y)dxdy$$
And in wikipedia it has given that,
$$\iint c(x,y)\gamma(x,y)dxdy = \int c(x,y)d\gamma(x,y)$$
My question is if we try to generalize this equation for all functions, does the following always hold true?
$$\iint u(x,y)v(x,y)dxdy = \int u(x,y)dv(x,y)$$
And if it is always true, I would like to have the proof of it.
